# why user is able to cd in to directory

Tags: permissions, directory

I'm doing a LAB from a RHCSA book and would like to ask for some help. The task is:

Log on to *host1* as *root* and create directory `/shared_dir1`. Create a group called `shared_grp` and assign `user1000` and `user2000` to it (create these users). Set up appropriate ownership, group membership, and permissions on the directory to support group collaboration.

What I've done so far:

1) created the /*shared_dir1* as *root*

```
mkdir /shared_dir1
```

2) create the group *shared_grp*

```
groupadd -g 9998 shared_grp
```

3) created both users

```
adduser user1000
adduser user2000
```

4) assigned user1000 and user2000 to the shared_grp

```
usermode -G shared_grp user1000
usermode -G shared_grp user2000
```

5) to support group collaboration I've set the setgid bit as follows

```
chmod g+s /shared_dir1
```

6)verified that the setgid bit is set properly

```
ls -ld /shared_dir1

drwxr-**s**r-x
```

7) changed group ownership from root to shared_grp:

```
chown root:shared_grp /shared_dir1
```

My first question is, why I'm able to `cd` in to the `/shared_dir1` (with user1000 or user2000 when according to the `ls` command the `/shared_dir1` is lacking the execute permission ?

Answer (score 2):

The lower-case 's' in the mode string means it is set-gid with executable. That string is a 2755 permissions set. If you remove the group executable bit but leave the setgid, you will see:

```
drwxr-Sr-x
```

which would be numerical mode 2745.

Comment: Thank you@John. I appreciate your help! My book was not mentioning it ;(  Just one more question. When they mention permissions and please correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't I have first to modify the groups permission on this particular directory e.g chmod g+w /shared_dir1   so that they can read, write to files in that directory? If yes, what about preventing from accidental and non accidental file deletion ? Should I also use the sticky bit along with the setgid ?Many thanks!